# I need to find the book code and book title for each book found in branch number 2 and written by author 20

Tags: mysql

want to find the book code and book title for each book found in branch number 2 and written by author 20.

The BOOK_CODE and TITLE are found in the "BOOK" table. BRANCH_NUM is found in the 'BRANCH' table.  The "AUTHOR" table has the AUTH_NUM AND BOOK_CODE.  I also have a table called 'INVENTORY' that has BOOK_CODE AND BRANCH_NUM and a table called WROTE that has BOOK_CODE and AUTHOR_NUM.

I would appreciate any help.  I'm just completely stuck.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT BOOK_CODE, TITLE 
FROM BOOK 
WHERE BOOK_CODE IN (SELECT BOOK_CODE FROM INVENTORY 
WHERE BRANCH_NUM = '2' AND AUTHOR_NUM = '20');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple `join` between the tables.

```
SELECT B.BOOK_CODE, B.TITLE
FROM BOOK B
JOIN WROTE W
ON W.BOOK_CODE = B.BOOK_CODE
AND W.AUTHOR_NUM ='20'
JOIN INVENTORY I
on I.BOOK_CODE = B.BOOK_CODE
AND I.BRANCH_NUM ='2'
```